# Is it possible to install LiveUSB persistent on NTFS or ext4?

Tags: live-usb, ntfs

Why liveUSB can be installed as persistent only on FAT/FAT32 where max file size is limited to 4GB?

Is it possible to choose another files system somehow, for example NTFS or EXT4 for liveUSB ubuntu persistent distro?

For me the problem is persistent file limit on FAT32 - 4 GB. I got 16GB pendrive and i wanna use full rest size of it for persistent data.

[Wikipedia / FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAT32#FAT32)

Comment: I think you are not looking for "persistent LiveUSB" but full installation in the USB.

Comment: There are two main alternatives for persistence in USB drives: 1. A persistent live drive, where you can have a partition for persistence, and an installed system (installed like into an internal drive). See this link with some tips and further links: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389 - 'Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it'.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu can be installed [persistently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence) on flash drives and has been shown to work on 64GB Sandisk and 16GB Kingston flash drives.

To do this, burn a live/install Ubuntu image to a DVD. Boot the DVD with the flash drive plugged in and begin the standard Ubuntu installation process, targeting the flash drive with the following partitions:

- A boot partition `/boot`, with about 250MB (ext4)
- A root partition `/root`, with at least 2GB (ext4)
- A swap partition `/swap`, with at least 2GB (format must be `swap`, not ext4)
- A home partition `/home`, with the remaining space (ext4)

Also be aware that ext4 is a journaling filesystem and care must be taken when using removable drives. [See Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/177529/htg-explains-why-are-removable-drives-still-using-fat32-instead-of-ntfs/) for more information.

Comment: well... ok then i will try to do simlar on my 16 GB pendrive

Comment: This is a full install on USB not a persistent USB.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the 4G limit by using an ext4 partition labeled "casper-rw" (and remove the file casper-rw after copying everything out).